# Why is UIBarButtonItem image always fuzzy/blurry/pixelated

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

Here is my current code:

```
var reply = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "reply"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("reply:"))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = reply
```

[image: img]The button in the top right corner is always fuzzy. This is a screenshot from an iPhone4s device so it is not a retina-related issue.

I have tried different image sizes ranging from 30x30 to 512x512 and adding the image using customView. These methods have not fixed the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved it using this method:

```
var replyBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
replyBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "reply"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
replyBtn.addTarget(self.navigationController, action: Selector("reply:"), forControlEvents:  UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
var item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: replyBtn)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
```

It displays a very crisp button using the exact same image.

Comment: If does not work with Swift 2 and xCode 6.4

            Replace last line
                   //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item 

         With
                   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = item

Answer (score 3):

From IOS human interface guide the icon should be 22x22
Take a look at the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func createBarButton(image: String, size: CGSize, offset: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) = (0,0), hightlightable: Bool = true, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let img = UIImage(named: image)

    btn.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: offset.x, y: offset.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    btn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = hightlightable
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
//        view.bounds = view.bounds.offsetBy(dx: offset.x, dy: offset.y)
    view.addSubview(btn)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)

    return barButton
}

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = createBarButton(image: "YOUR_IMAGE",
     size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35),
     offset: (x: -10, y: 0),
     action: #selector(showXY))
```